# uninstalling microsoft office 2007 and updates

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, uninstall

I am running Vista and have microsoft office 2007 trial that came preinstalled.  I now have office 2010 and would like to know if i can uninstall office 2007 and all its updates, or, will the updates automatically uninstall?

Answer (score 1):

You can uninstall Microsoft Office 2007 without any issues, it will also remove the updates when you completely uninstall it. You can then install Microsoft Office 2010 and update that. You do not need to remove the updates individually.